# cout variable and function that change variable by reference

Tags: c++

Suppose we have next code:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int change(int &temp){
    temp += 2;
    return 10;
}

int main(){
    int nmb = 2;

    cout << change(nmb) << " " << nmb << endl;
}
```

I thought it should work like cout would print out new value of nmb but it prints the old version of nmb.

Instead of wanted result 10 4, I get the result 10 2. 
Why does cout prints out old value of nmb, as cout first print out change then it prints nmb?

I have compiled it under g++, using standard c++11.

Comment: `cout << change(nmb) << " "; cout << nmb << endl;` and you get your result

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<s>No, the order of evaluation is implementation defined.</s>

The order of evaluation is unspecified until C++17. (Please see the comments and M.M's answer.)

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order

Comment: So I can't do it like cout << func(nmb) << " " << nmb?

Comment: If `func` modified `nmb`, the specification won't say what will happen and different compilers can produce code that evaluates the expressions in either order.

Comment: Your link does not support the claim that the order is implementation-defined

Comment: @M.M To be honest, I was a little confused by rule 19, but in the cout and i++ example for undefined behavior 2, the reference said that it was undefined...

Comment: In that example it is undefined behaviour because `i++` modifies `i`, but is unsequenced against the other read of `i`

Comment: @M.M Isn't that the exact same case as OP's example? Or are function call mutations treated differently? Rule 19 says, "In a shift operator expression E1<<E2 and E1>>E2, every value computation and side-effect of E1 is sequenced before every value computation and side effect of E2."  But, `i` is E1 and `i++` is E2, right? Since you probably know the standard better than me, isn't the value computation `i` sequenced before the value computation and side effect of `i++`?

Comment: OP's example is a function call, `i++` is not a function call. The body of a function is indeterminately sequenced with respect to the calling context (not unsequenced like `i++`).

Comment: To clarify my earlier comment: prior to C++17 `cout << i << i++` was undefined and OP's code unspecified; since C++17 both are well-defined. You still haven't offered any evidence for your claim of it being implementation-defined  (the cppreference link does not mention "implementation defined" anywhere)

Comment: @M.M I'm sorry for adding an incorrect answer. If the OP un-chooses mine, I will delete it. You can downvote my answer so my misinformation isn't spread.

Comment: You could edit it to say "unspecified" instead of "implementation defined" (and perhaps mention that you were talking about prior to C++17 which has only just been released)

Answer (score 4):

Since C++17, the `operator<<` has left-right sequencing (i.e. the left operand is sequenced before the right operand). So if you use a compiler that conforms to the latest standard you should see `10 4`.  (Ref: N4659 [over.match.oper]/2,
 [expr.shift]/4)

Prior to C++17 it was unspecified.